# How to average adjacent columns (non-overlapping) in R using dplyr function?

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, average

This is a sample of my dataset.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

resource <- c("good","good","bad","bad","good","good","bad","bad","good","good","bad","bad","good","good","bad","bad")

fertilizer <- c("none", "nitrogen","none","nitrogen","none", "nitrogen","none","nitrogen","none", "nitrogen","none","nitrogen","none", "nitrogen","none","nitrogen")

t1 <-  sample(1:20, 16) 
t2 <-  sample(1:20, 16)
t3 <-  sample(1:20, 16)
t4 <-  sample(1:20, 16)
t5 <-  sample(1:20, 16)
t6 <-  sample(10:100, 16)
t7 <-  sample(10:100, 16)
t8 <-  sample(10:100, 16)
t9 <-  sample(10:100, 16)
t10 <-  sample(10:100, 16)

replicates <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)

data <- data.frame(resource, fertilizer,replicates, t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10)

data$resource <- as.factor(data$resource)
data$fertilizer <- as.factor(data$fertilizer)
```

Where t0,t1,t2..etc are time points. I need to average adjacent time points (non-overlapping) across eg. (t1,t2), (t3,t4)..and the new column headings need to have the average of the times, so that the columns read as t1.5,t3.5,...etc.
Thus in the end I need to have only 5 columns reading t1.5, t3.5,t5.5, t7.5,t9.5

Is there anyway this can be achieved using dplyr function, or any other function in R?

Comment: Do `resource`, `fertilizer`, and `replicates` serve any purpose in this example?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to toggle the dataset to calculate the averages without having to remove them from the data-set completely

Comment: Makes sense. I have incorporated your edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited for OP's modified request:

If you put everything in a tidy format, you can take advantage of the lag/lead functions to average adjacent rows.

```
library(stringr)
library(forcats)

data %>% 
  gather(key = time, value = value, -replicates, -resource, -fertilizer) %>% 
  mutate(index = as.integer(str_extract(time, "[0-9]+"))) %>% 
  arrange(replicates, index) %>% 
  group_by(resource, fertilizer, replicates) %>% 
  mutate(mid_value = (value + lead(value))/2,
         mid_index = (index + lead(index))/2,
         mid_time = str_c("t",mid_index)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  filter(!is.na(mid_value), index %% 2 == 1) %>% 
  select(replicates, resource, fertilizer, matches("mid")) %>% 
  rename(value = mid_value, time = mid_time, index = mid_index) %>%
  arrange(index) %>% 
  mutate(time = as_factor(time)) %>% 
  select(-index) %>% 
  spread(key = time, value = value) %>% 
  arrange(replicates)
```

Comment: I need only 5 columns in the end with the averages. Not all the columns AND their averages. I have updated my question more clearly to reflect the same

Comment: Modified the answer

Comment: I think it still has 10 columns. I was looking to average adjacent columns, but they do not overlap for eg. (t1,t2),(t3,t4),(t5,t6)..so that way I would have 5. Also can we store the new output in a separate data frame?

Comment: I edited it to filter out overlapping columns.  Surely you can assign the output to a separate data frame without assistance?

Comment: Yes, I can. Thanks for this. It was useful

Answer (score 1):

Solution using only base `R`: You need to somehow find the columns you want to calculate the average for. You can do this by searching the column names for the `t + "somenumber"` pattern. After that, create a sequence of sequences, corresponding to the column numbers of `df` you want to calculate the mean for.

```
relevant_cols <- grep("[0-9]{1,2}", names(df))
start <- min(relevant_cols)
end   <- max(relevant_cols)
cols  <- split(start:end, rep(1:5, each=2))
```

If you look at `cols`, you'll see that it is list of five, each element resembling a combination of columns you want to average. This smells like a use-case for `sapply()`:

```
newdf <- sapply(cols, function(x) rowMeans(df[x]) )
colnames(newdf) <- paste0("t", seq(1, diff(range(relevant_cols)), 2) + 0.5)
```

Edit: I seem to have misunderstood what you want to maintain and what not. You can just `cbind()` (parts of) the old `df` to `newdf`:

```
cbind(df, newdf)
cbind(df[, -relevant_cols], newdf)   # This is what you want. I think..
```

Comment: But this does not allow me to toggle and keep the other variables like fertilizer, resource etc. It just creates a df with averages. I need the other information

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
transmute(data, 
          t1.5 = (t1 + t2) / 2,
          t3.5 = (t3 + t4) / 2,
          t5.5 = (t5 + t6) / 2,
          t7.5 = (t7 + t8) / 2,
          t9.5 = (t9 + t10) / 2)
```

Comment: I need only 5 columns in the end with the averages of the non-overlapping columns. I have updated my question more clearly to reflect the same